# What happens if you use submit() function in javascript for a form that contains multiple submit options?

Tags: form-submit, submit-button

I have an HTML form (id="myForm") that has multiple submit buttons:

```
<button type="submit" name="save" value="save">Save</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
```

If I use the javascript submit() function on this form element, which submit option gets executed?

Answer (score 0):

Both submit buttons and JavaScript submit will be the same till you differentiate the handler url or form action for each use case.

For JavaScript it will use the action attribute inside form tag. For the submit buttons you can specify different action inside button tag using `formaction`attribute.